# FBRSS.com replacement for RSS feed from Wall to WordPress Syndicate Press Plugin

Tags: facebook, wordpress, rss, feed

My WordPress page displayed wall info from multiple Facebook accounts using FBRSS.com to stream RSS feeds from 3 Facebook walls to the Syndicate Press Plugin.
But the FBRSS.com site is down.  Any suggestions for a replacement or different solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have one information. It's so [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/).
Meant a "**If** **T**his **T**hen **T**hat".

1. This = Channel of Trigger.
2. Then = Trigger.
3. That = Action for Channel.

Channel is many. Now on 49 channels. It's many Social and Web services. Require activate on operation.

Trigger is many on channel. Example....

Facebook ( User ): Trigger

1. New status message by you.
2. New link post by you.
3. You upload a new photo.
4. You are tagged in a photio.
5. Your profile changes.

Facebook ( Page ): Trigger

1. New status message on page.
2. New link post on page.
3. New photo on page.

Action too many....

Facebook ( User ): Action

1. Create a status message.
2. Create a link post.
3. Upload a new photo from URL.

Facebook ( Page ): Action

1. Create a status message.
2. Create a link post.
3. Upload a new photo from URL.

Include your need?
If your FBRSS.com service are restarted. But this service interest!
Please using it.

Interst: Using a "Date & Time" and "Phone" = Morning call!!!

Thank you, Regards.